# Configuring capture card to get audio out to the speakers

Tags: windows-xp, audio, tuner-card

I have been using my capture card as a video in device so I can play my video game systems without having to go to the TV in another room. I have been trying to get the audio to play through line-in, to no avail. Would there be a way to make the audio from line-in to output the video game console audio from the computer? Also, I'm on Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VLC to play it back

Set by set howto:

1. Open VLC
2. Press File
3. Open Capture Device
4. Select the capture card
5. Press Open.